# typedef an array with const elements using const ArrayType or ConstArrayType in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, typedef

I am going to define some arrays with fixed size and const elements.
I tried to use `typedef`, but there seems to be something confused:

```
typedef int A[4];
typedef const int CA[4];

const A a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
CA ca = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

a[0] = 0;
ca[0] = 0;
a = ca;
ca = a;
```

All assignments will cause syntax error in the code above which I think `a[0] = 0;` should be legal before my test.

Considering pointers,
the result is much easier to understand that `p[0] = 0;` and `cp = p;` is correct.

```
typedef int *P;
typedef const int *CP;

const P p = new int[4]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
CP cp = new int[4]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

p[0] = 0;
cp[0] = 0;
p = cp;
cp = p;
```

Why does the cv-qualifier behave different on pointer and array?
Is it because the array has already been a const pointer, then the compiler makes some implicit conversion?

P.S. I compiled the code on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You could try std::array instead.

Comment: I don't think you can use `const` in a `typedef` because it's not a type specifier it's a qualifier, I had never thought of doing that because it doesn't make any sense at all I suppose.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays. If you get a *syntax* error (rather than any other compilation error) on the assignments, you're doing them at file scope, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Also, that is a very bad idea for a `typedef`, and in c++ it's even a worst idea, because you can use templates to achieve the same effect in a generic way, and you can define an `array` class or use on of the standard template library.

Comment: Also, complete examples and verbatim copies of error messages help immensely for those trying to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two declarations

```
const A a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
CA ca = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

are fully equivalent and declare constant arrays. If you will run this simple program (for example using MS VC++)

```
#include<iostream>

typedef const int CA[4];
typedef int A[4];

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid( CA ).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid( const A ).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

you will get the same result for the both output statements

```
int const [4]
int const [4]
```

In fact you could write instead

```
#include<iostream>

typedef int A[4];
typedef const A CA;

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid( CA ).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid( const A ).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

with the same result.

As for pointer declarators then the semantic has a minor difference. You may use cv-qualifiers with pointer declarators

```
ptr-operator:
    * attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
```

That is you may write for example

```
typedef const int * const P;
```

(constant pointer that points to constant data).

Thus if you will write

```
typedef int *P;
```

and then write

```
typedef const P CP;
```

when `CP` will be a constant pointer. The object it points to is not constant. Only the pointer itself is constant and may not be changed. That is declaration

```
typedef const P CP;
```

is equivalent to

```
typedef int * const CP;
```

It is not the same as

```
typedef const int *CP;
```

where in the last declaration the pointer itself is not constant. It is the object pointed to by a pointer having this type will be constant and may not be changed using this pointer.

Shortly speaking if you have

```
typedef int A[4];
```

then

```
const A a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

is equivalent to

```
const int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

If you have

```
typedef int *P;
```

then

```
const P p = new int[4]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

is equivalent to

```
int * const p = new int[4]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Take into account that if you have declaration like

```
const int *p;
```

then you need not to initialize the pointer because it is not constant.

While when you have declaration like

```
int * const p = new int;
```

or like

```
const int * const p = new int;
```

you shall initialize the pointer because it is a constant. Otherwise the compiler will issue an error.

Answer (score 2):

I searched cppreference again and again and finially found the answer...

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array

It is said that

> Applying cv-qualifiers to an array type (through typedef or template
>   type manipulation) applies the qualifiers to the element type, but any
>   array type whose elements are of cv-qualified type is considered to
>   have the same cv-qualification.
>
> ```
> // arr1 and arr2 have the same const-qualified type "array of 5 const char"
> typedef const char CC;
> CC arr1[5] = {}; 
> typedef char CA[5];
> const CA arr2 = {};
> ```

which is exactly what I am asking for!
Usually,
`typedef const PointerType p;` means that `p` can not be modified but the data pointed by `p` is mutable, and `typedef const Type *cp;` means `cp` is mutable but the data pointed by `cp` is constant.

But for an array, these two styles are equivalent!

Comment: C-style arrays have weird behaviour, which is why it's often recommended to not use them in C++

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but maybe the following will be helpful.

In the first case, `a[0]=0;` fails because the type of a is `const int[]`. I like reading const from right to left.

```
typedef int IntegerArraySz4[4];
IntegerArraySz4 const a; // constant array, assignment not allowed
```

In the second case, there is a difference in your typedefs between a pointer to a constant integer array and a constant pointer to an integer array. Again, from right to left:

```
typedef int* IntPointer;
typedef int const* ConstantIntPointer;

// This is a constant pointer to some memory
IntPointer const p = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
p[2] = 1; // okay

// This is a pointer to some constant memory
ConstantIntPointer cp = new int [4] { 1, 3, 4, 5 };
cp[2] = 1; // error
```

Answer (score 0):

It you want a C-style array you'll need to use a macro:

```
#define A(x) int x[4]
#define CA(x) const int x[4]
```

Which would be used like:

```
const A(a) = {1, 2, 3, 4};
CA(ca) = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

But that appears very confusing. Using `std::array<int, 4>` seems by far preferable. And you could do that with a `typedef`:

```
typedef array<int, 4> A;
typedef const array<int, 4> CA;
```

Which would be used like:

```
const A a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
CA ca = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Note that the remainder of your code is illegal since you cannot assign to a `const array` or a `const int[]`.